# Next.js environment setting for emotion/react and TailwindCSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, emotion

I'm trying to use emotion/react and TailwindCss in my projects. But I got stuck.

Of course, If I add `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` to every component, I'm able to use both libraries, but I want to find a way to not add the pragma for all of my components.

Here is what I tried:

1. Changing my tsconfig.
   I add     `"jsx": "preserve", "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",` to my tsconfig.
2. I set my babelrc like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
}
```

3. Changing the __document.tsx

```
import Document, {
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentContext,
} from "next/document";
import { extractCritical } from "@emotion/server";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    const styles = extractCritical(initialProps.html);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: (
        <>
          {initialProps.styles}
          <style
            data-emotion-css={styles.ids.join(" ")}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: styles.css }}
          />
        </>
      ),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

The emotion css still not applied even though I set it like this.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you.